# Torch JIT Trace = TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python boolean might cause the trace to be incorrect

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, torchscript

I am following this tutorial: https://huggingface.co/transformers/torchscript.html
to create a trace of my custom BERT model, however when running the exact same `dummy_input` I receive an error:

```
TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python boolean might cause the trace to be incorrect. 
We cant record the data flow of Python values, so this value will be treated as a constant in the future.
```

Having loaded in my model and tokenizer, the code to create the trace is the following:

```
text = "[CLS] Who was Jim Henson ? [SEP] Jim Henson was a puppeteer [SEP]"
tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

# Masking one of the input tokens
masked_index = 8
tokenized_text[masked_index] = '[MASK]'
indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text)
segments_ids = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
segments_tensors = torch.tensor([segments_ids])
dummy_input = [tokens_tensor, segments_tensors]

traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, dummy_input)
```

The `dummy_input` is a list of tensors so I'm not sure where the `Boolean` type is coming into play here. Does anyone understand why this error is occurring and whether the Boolean conversion is happening?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 18):

### What this error means

This **warning** occurs, when one tries to `torch.jit.trace` models which have **data dependent control flow**.

This simple example should make it clearer:

```
import torch


class Foo(torch.nn.Module):
    def forward(self, tensor):
        # It is data dependent
        # Trace will only work with one path
        if tensor.max() > 0.5:
            return tensor ** 2
        return tensor


model = Foo()
traced = torch.jit.script(model) # No warnings
traced = torch.jit.trace(model, torch.randn(10)) # Warning
```

In essence, BERT model has some control flow (like `if`, `for` loop) dependent on the data, hence you get the warning.

### Warning itself

You can see BERT `forward` code [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L874).

You are fine if:

- arguments do not change (like `None` values passed to `forward`) and it will stay that way after `script` (e.g. during inference calls)
- if there is control flow based on data gathered inside `__init__` (like configs), because this will not change

For example:

```
elif input_ids is not None:
    input_shape = input_ids.size()
    batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
```

Will only run as one branch with `torch.jit.trace`, as it just traces operations on tensor and is unaware of control flow like this.

HuggingFace teams is probably aware of that and this warning is not an issue (though you might double check with your use case or try to go with `torch.jit.script`)

### Going with `torch.jit.script`

This one would be hard as the whole model has to be `torchscript` compatible (`torchscript` has a subset of Python available and more than likely will not work out of the box with BERT).

Do it only when necessary (probably not).